# Adding git alias with pipes complains about wrong configuration

Tags: git, git-alias

I am trying to add a git alias that makes me abort a rebase that have just finished. I tried to add this in `.gitconfig`:

```
rebabort = !sh -c 'git reflog | grep -v rebase | head -1 | sed -e "s/^\([[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1/g" | git reset --hard'
```

but it complains about a wrong configuration. Anyway I tried to add the alias in the following way:

```
git config alias.rebabort '!git reflog | grep -v rebase | head -1 | sed -e "s/^\([[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1/g" | git reset --hard'
```

and it worked. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I also tried to add this in `.gitconfig`

```
rebabort = "!f() { \
                git reflog | grep -v rebase | head -1 | sed -e 's/^\([[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1/g\' | git reset --hard;
    }; f"
```

and this

```
rebabort = !"git reflog | grep -v rebase | head -1 | sed -e 's/^\([[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1/g' | git reset --hard"
```

but it still complains about wrong configuration.

Comment: What shell are you using and on what OS?  This is likely an OS+shell specific problem rather than a git problem.

Comment: Bash on Mac Yosemite.

Comment: Was your first command exactly like that? It looks like it's missing a closing apostrophe `'` symbol to match the first one for the `sh -c` option.

Comment: @starlocke I missed it in the question, it was present when I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replicated your "line that worked" and then looked in my dummy project's `.git/config` and found the following:

```
[alias]
        rebabort = !git reflog | grep -v rebase | head -1 | sed -e s/^\\([[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*\\)\\(.*\\)/\\1/g | git reset --hard
```

Just copy that to your `~/.gitconfig`

It looks like a simple matter of not needing the `sh -c` stuff.  Your .gitconfig is not a `.bashrc`; I say this because it looked like you were trying to write an alias in `.bashrc` format.

Also, for your reference, you could have done the following for the same effect (your line that worked, PLUS the `--global`) option, since `--global` typically adds to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
git config --global alias.rebabort '!git reflog | grep -v rebase | head -1 | sed -e "s/^\([[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1/g" | git reset --hard'
```

The help files for `git config` are very informative for learning new options and tricks, too. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config